# Python Connected Components from edges stream

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I would like to find connected components from a edges stream

In input i have a stream like this :

```
edges_in : [(e1,e2),(e2,e3),(e3,e1),(e5,e6)]
edges_out: : [(e1,e2)]
```

I'm looking for an algorithm to have in the output:

```
connected_edges : [[(e2,e3),(e3,e1)],[(e5,e6)]]
```

And from this connected_edges list have :

```
connected_nodes : [[e2,e3,e1],[e5,e6]]
```

I need to have this method for maintain components

I have tried all graph library (like networkX, igraph) in python and some code in the web but any work.

Your help is precious.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) can solve this problem.

This data structure has ability of online joining elements to groups. And in each group you may have label with used edges.